# Get the Unicode value of a TCHAR

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi

I need to get the Unicode value of a TCHAR.

e.g. if the TCHAR = "A", I want to find the Unicode value of 0x41.

Is it safe to cast to an int, or is there an API function I should be using?

Comment: Define "unicode value". The raw table number (=UTF-32 number)?

Comment: A `TCHAR` can be either a `char` or a `WCHAR` (`wchar_t`) depending on how you are compiling your code, and the answer to your question depends on which.  You need to be clearer about what you are doing.  Whichever it is, a cast probably isn't the right answer.

Comment: I've clarified my question.

Comment: Step 1 is to stop using TCHAR. That was so you could write code for Win 95 and Win NT. The former was ANSI, the latter handled Unicode. It's now 2014. You don't support Win 9x anymore right? So stop using TCHAR and pick wchar_t.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a little mal-formed. A `TCHAR` can be either an 8 bit or a 16 bit character. In and of itself, it's not enough to know how wide the character is. You also need to know how it is encoded. For example:

- If you have an 8 bit ASCII encoded character, then its numeric value is the Unicode code point.
- If you have an 8 bit Windows ANSI encoded character from a single byte character set you convert to UTF-16 with `MultiByteToWideChar`. The numeric value of the UTF-16 element is the Unicode code point.
- If you have an 8 bit Windows ANSI encoded character element from a double byte or multi byte character set, that 8 bit char does not, in general, define a character. In general, you need multiple char elements.
- Likewise for a 16 bit UTF-16 encoded character element. Again UTF-16 is a variable width encoding and a single character element does not in general define a Unicode code point.

So, in order to proceed you must become clear as to how your character is encoded.

Before even doing that you need to know how wide it is. `TCHAR` can be 8 bit or 16 bit, depending on how you compile. That flexibility was how we handled single source development for Win 9x and Win NT. The former had no Unicode support. Nowadays Win 9x is, thankfully long forgotten and so too should `TCHAR`. Sadly it lives on in countless MSDN examples but you should ignore that. On Windows the native character element is `wchar_t`.

Comment: UTF-16 values are not always the value of unicode code point since there are surrogate pairs

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Yes, I said that very clearly in the final bullet point. But in the second bullet point, the result of calling `MultiByteToWideChar` in that scenario is not a surrogate pair.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i just guess you want UTF-32 numbers.
Arx said it already, `TCHAR` can be `char` or `wchar_t`.

If you have a `char`-string, it probably will contain data
with the default single-byte charset of your system (`UTF-8` is possible too)
As dealing with many different charsets is difficult
and Windows has builtin conversion stuff:
Use `MultiByteToWideChar` to get a `wchar_t`-array of your `char`-array.

If you have a `wchar_t`-array, it´s most likely `UTF-16` (LE, without BOM...) on Windows.
I don´t know any built-in function to get `UTF-32` of it,
but writing an own conversion is not that hard (else, use some lib)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16
Some bit-fiddling, but nothing more.

(What `TCHAR` is is a preprocessor-thing,
so you could implement different behaviour
based on the `#define`´s too. Or `sizeof` or...)